# Symfony & Easy Admin : How to apply easyadmin template to custom form

Tags: forms, templates, easyadmin

I created a custom form for and integrated it in easyadmin. the forms is displayed, filled and action is working, but the templating is not good :

[image]

Here is my Twig :

```
    {% extends "@EasyAdmin/page/content.html.twig" %}
{% form_theme form with easyadmin_config('design.form_theme') only %}

{% block body_id 'easyadmin-edit-User-1' %}
{% block body_class 'edit edit-user' %}
{% block content_title %}
        <h1 class="title">Edit Account</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content_footer_wrapper '' %}
{% block main %}
    {% block entity_form %}
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    {% endblock entity_form %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body_javascript %}
    {{ include('@EasyAdmin/default/includes/_select2_widget.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

and my controller :

```
class UserController extends EasyAdminController
{
    public function editaccountAction(UserInterface $loggedUser, Request $request) {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $id = $loggedUser->getId();
        $entity = $repository->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $entity);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var Article $article */
            $entity= $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Account Saved');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('easyadmin');
        }
        return $this->render('user/editaccs.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can I have the same form presentation as edit?

Answer (score 2):

Before

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
```

add

```
{% form_theme form '@EasyAdmin/form/bootstrap_4.html.twig' %}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-single-forms

**UPD:**

In EasyAdmin 4.3 theme would be

```
{% form_theme form '@EasyAdmin/crud/form_theme.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Your solution maybe worked earlier but doesn't work with the current one (6.1.x / 4.3.x). Could you update your answer and add the version to it or add different solutions for the different versions?

Comment: @ZoltánSüle Updated answer

Comment: that template doesn't support the Light/Dark appearance. So it is better to use `{% form_theme form '@EasyAdmin/crud/form_theme.html.twig' %}`